# HT Access - Redirect to subfolder & keep other folders accessible

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I've installed a new WordPress website in a subfolder at www.mydomain.com, and it want every request for this root to point to my new site under www.mydomain.com/new.

I did get this working my researching, but found that any new subfolder I add to my domain comes back with a Page Not Found page from WordPress. Is it possible to keep all new subfolders in the domain accessible?

Also, I found that there are now two instances of my front page, one at mydomain and one at my domain.com/new ... Can I just make sure that the request just goes to domain.com/new?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you, assuming a WordPress installation on /new/:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi Sergio, I tried this but it doesn't work. Although I did change /new/index.php to /2012-folio/ ... this is where my WordPress site is stored. Perhaps it should be different? Here is what I have in my .htaccess file now:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /2012-folio/ [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: By the way, I'm using it in the .htaccess file in the root of my domain, not in the WordPress folder. Thanks for your help.